# Modx installation: deprecated: mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, modx-revolution

I use Ubuntu 13.10. After installing Modx I get this warning:

```
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /var/www/test.loc/manager/includes/extenders/dbapi.mysql.class.inc.php on line 93
```

Help me, please!

Comment: simple... use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty much written in the warning; Use [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_* functions like mysql_query, mysql_connect, mysql_select_db and other function of this library are deprecated from php5.5 and above due to lack of new features and security vulnerabilities.

Now you should try to use mysqli or PDO for your future applications. These new APIs support Transactions, Stored Procedures and Prepared statements that provide a way to avoid sql injection attacks.

Although t is possible to suppress such error messages and continue using the old mysql library but you should not do this.